# What's the difference between free energy and potential energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I found different answers for this question. Was wondering to find a way to explain it to my students how to illustrate the two concepts in practical terms.

Comment: I'd rather wonder what they have in common.

Comment: @Mithoron Both are measured in Joules. Other than that, hardly anything.